# Recommended strategies for backing up appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

Right now I use remote_api and `appcfg.py download_data` to take a snapshot of my database every night. It takes a long time (6 hours) and is expensive.  Without rolling my own change-based backup (I'd be too scared to do something like that), what's the best option for making sure my data is safe from failure?

PS: I recognize that Google's data is probably way safer than mine.  But what if one day I accidentally write a program that deletes it all?

Comment: About your last question, star this bug: [776](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=776)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've pretty much identified all of your choices.

1. Trust Google not to lose your data, and hope you don't accidentally instruct them to destroy it.
2. Perform full backups with `download_data`, perhaps less frequently than once per night if it is prohibitively expensive.
3. Roll your own incremental backup solution.

Option 3 is actually an interesting idea. You'd need a modification timestamp on all entities, and you wouldn't catch deleted entities, but otherwise it's very doable with remote_api and cursors.

**Edit**:

Here's a simple incremental downloader for use with remote_api. Again, the caveats are that it won't notice deleted entities, and it assumes all entities store the last modification time in a property named updated_at. Use it at your own peril.

```
import os
import hashlib
import gzip
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.ext.db.metadata import Kind
from google.appengine.api.datastore import Query
from google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query import Cursor

INDEX = 'updated_at'
BATCH = 50
DEPTH = 3

path = ['backups', app_identity.get_application_id()]
for kind in Kind.all():
  kind = kind.kind_name
  if kind.startswith('__'):
    continue
  while True:
    print 'Fetching %d %s entities' % (BATCH, kind)
    path.extend([kind, 'cursor.txt'])
    try:
      cursor = open(os.path.join(*path)).read()
      cursor = Cursor.from_websafe_string(cursor)
    except IOError:
      cursor = None
    path.pop()
    query = Query(kind, cursor=cursor)
    query.Order(INDEX)
    entities = query.Get(BATCH)
    for entity in entities:
      hash = hashlib.sha1(str(entity.key())).hexdigest()
      for i in range(DEPTH):
        path.append(hash[i])
      try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(*path))
      except OSError:
        pass
      path.append('%s.xml.gz' % entity.key())
      print 'Writing', os.path.join(*path)
      file = gzip.open(os.path.join(*path), 'wb')
      file.write(entity.ToXml())
      file.close()
      path = path[:-1-DEPTH]
    if entities:
      path.append('cursor.txt')
      file = open(os.path.join(*path), 'w')
      file.write(query.GetCursor().to_websafe_string())
      file.close()
      path.pop()
    path.pop()
    if len(entities) < BATCH:
      break
```